# Exists nmap extended version for the parameter -sV (service/version info)

Tags: security, parameters, nmap, port-scanning

I am trying to find a longer format for the **-sV** option that triggers version information for services while port scanning, however neither in the man page or info page from nmap is saying anything.

The reason of using longer/extender parameter format is for readability for some tests avoiding putting so many comments when have so many parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no long-format option for any of the scan type options (`-sV`, `-sS`, `-sU`, etc.). As a general rule, Nmap options are either long or short; while some have similar meanings (`-sC` and `--script`), their usage is different, so they are not interchangeable.